# Starting jupyter notebook programmatically from another notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

Is it possible to start another notebook from the current notebook? I know how to create and save the current notebook but I cannot launch another notebook from the current one.
%run does not work while starting another notebook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I suppose you know the url for the notebook you want to open you could open it in the following way:

This code should be a code cell in your notebook:

```
%%javascript
window.open('http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Name_of_the_notebook.ipynb')
```

If you don't know the complete path (url) to the notebook you should, at least, know the name of the notebook you created. In this case you could do:

```
%%javascript
var name_of_the_notebook = 'Name_of_the_notebook.ipynb'
var url = window.location.href.split('/')
var newurl = url[0] + '//'
for (var i = 1; i < url.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(url[i], newurl)
    newurl += url[i] + '/'
}
newurl += name_of_the_notebook
window.open(newurl)
```

Maybe the browser will ask if you want to open the new tab.

Comment: UsageError: Line magic function `%%javascript` not found.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of kikocorreoso should open the specified notebook at launch. When this is not required or desirable, you can simply create a clickable link (even relative) in a Markdown cell, *i.e.*:

```
Click to open your [notebook](../others/name_of_the_notebook.ipynb).
```

Comment: can you please write in more details how to do that? simple copy-paste does not work (as expected)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Jupyter Notebook server, you can copy the URL of an open Notebook and paste it into a HTML hyperlink in a different notebook's markdown cell.

For example, in a markdown cell put <a href="http://localhost:8888/notebooks/examples/Backup.ipynb">bakup</a>.  Run the cell.  Click on the hyperlink and the linked notebook will open in a new tab.  This has been tested on Windows 11 with the Edge browser.

I have not been able to accomplish this with Jupyter Lab, yet.