Running multiple notebooks at the same time
I want to run multiple python notebooks simultaneously and I am unsure how I can do this. I want to have one notebook which I can use to run the other notebooks. They have no relation to each other and I simply want this for convenience.
I have tried the %run function but this runs one notebooks, completes it and then starts the next one (example below) but this doesn't work as the notebooks are running loops, waiting for an external factor.
%run apple.ipynb
%run pear.ipynb


Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37858179/15031004
